# Effect of tweaking numFolds parameter on REPTree classifier on Weka

Tags: weka

I use REPTree as classifier on Weka. I got 93% for correctly classified instances. When i change the numFold value from 3 to 5, the correctly classified instances increase to 94%. Can i know whats the significance of numFold in this matter ?

Answer (score 0):

(Click on the "More" Button within the window where you've changed 3 to 5.)

The documentation says "numFolds -- Determines the amount of data used for pruning. One fold is used for pruning, the rest for growing the rules."

To my understanding, "pruning" means automatically cutting back many intermediate,  sparsely populated tree-leaves in order to make the decision tree more simple and understandable.

If you want to even more severely restrict tree size, set maxDepth to 3 or so.